# Check neighbors gives weird segmentation fault. Game of Life in C

Tags: c

I'm making a game of life with a 2 dimensional grid of 8192 x 8192. I found through the use of print statements that getNeighbours() is causing a segmentation error when it is given y=8191 and x=1000.

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int GRIDSIZE = 8192;
int grid[8192][8192];

// counts the amount of live neighbours to y, x
int getNeighbours(int y, int x){
    int neighbours = 0;
    // if not at top check up
    if (y > 0) neighbours = neighbours + grid[y - 1][x] == 1;
    // if not at bottom check below
    if (y < GRIDSIZE) neighbours = neighbours + grid[y + 1][x] == 1; // This will cause segmentation fault at y 8191 x 1000
    if (y == GRIDSIZE - 1) printf("%d, %d\n", y, x);
    // if not at leftmost check left
    if (x > 0) neighbours = neighbours + grid[y][x - 1] == 1;
    // if not at rightmost check right
    if (x < GRIDSIZE) neighbours = neighbours + grid[y][x+1] == 1;

    return neighbours;
}
```

Comment: `if (y < GRIDSIZE)` ==> `if (y < GRIDSIZE-1)` and similar `x`

Comment: BTW `grid[y - 1][x] == 1` is simpler as `grid[y - 1][x]` if the cell contains `0` or `1`. But there is another fault – you are supposed to check diagonals too: 8 neighbours not 4.

Answer (score 3):

Your grid size is `8192x8192` but your your array index range is from `0` to `8191`. So when you supply `8191` for `y`, that line causes a segmentation fault because the index of `y+1` which is `8191+1=8192` is out of range.

Answer (score 0):

My if statement was wrong very simple, just subtract 1 from GRIDSIZE when making sure you aren't at the boundry.

before

```
if (y < GRIDSIZE) neighbours = neighbours + grid[y + 1][x] == 1;
```

after

```
if (y < GRIDSIZE - 1) neighbours = neighbours + grid[y + 1][x] == 1;
```